# Bizzare ODBC connection failure when switching between data sources

Tags: c#, .net, odbc

This question is a spin off of a question I asked about [connection pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528158/net-sql-server-connection-issue-maybe-connection-pool-related).

Using ODBC I am getting the following error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The connection has been disabled. --->     
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
[DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite (send()).

ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General network error. 
Check your network documentation.

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.ConnectionIsAlive(Exception innerException) ...
```

Here is the code that can reproduce the issue each time but only on a single client machine (client is Windows 7 64-bit, .NET 4.5.2, SQL Server Express, Adagio ODBC)

```
try
{
using (var dyn = new OdbcConnection("dsn=test;UID=test;PWD=test")) // uses ODBC for sql server
{
    dyn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM COMPANY", dyn))
    {
        using (cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

        }
    }
    dyn.Close();
}

using (var dyn = new OdbcConnection("dsn=Adagio Data Source")) // uses 3rd party ODBC
{
    dyn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT COMPANY FROM AL92AGLO", dyn))
    {
        using (cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

        }
    }
    dyn.Close();
}

using (var dyn = new OdbcConnection("dsn=test;UID=test;PWD=test"))
{

    dyn.Open(); // EXCEPTION THROWN !!!

    using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM COMPANY", dyn))
    {
        using (cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

        }
    }
    dyn.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
}
```

So the connection works just fine when connection to SQL server with ODBC and then I can connect to the 3rd party ODBC (Adagio) but when I try to connect to SQL server again I get "connection has been disabled".

Originally I was trying to use SqlConnection object but it would through an exception that I could not catch and the application would crash with:

```
System.AccessViolationException
<Module>.SNIOpenSyncExWrapper(SNI_CLIENT_CONSUMER_INFO*, SNI_ConnWrapper**)
at SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIOpenSyncEx(ConsumerInfo, System.String, IntPtr ByRef, Byte[], Byte[], Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Boolean)
at System.Data.SqlClient
```

Googling I came across an article indicating this can happen with .NET 4.5.1.  The client did have .NET 4.5.1 so we updated to .NET 4.5.2 but that didn't solve the problem.

If I attempt to connect again after the failed connection with ODBC it works but my application framework uses SqlConnection which throws an uncatchable exception so I cannot simply try again.

I feel like I am on the fringe of 3rd party implementation of ODBC and Microsoft .NET bugs.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What do you have in the `test` DSN?

Comment: I am using ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server and pointed to SQL Server database.